# AngularJS - Programmatically check whether filter exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is there a way to programmatically check whether a filter with a given name exists?

I developed a directive to process page content based on a string input, I want it to react differently in case a certain part of the string corresponds to a filter that exists in my system. For example I have a localize filter:

```
// Somewhere in the code
var myInput = 'localize';

// Somewhere else
var contentToProcess = 'my content';
var result = '';
if ($filter.hasOwnProperty(myInput))    // TODO: this is the part I'm trying to figure out
    result = $filter(myInput)(contentToProcess);
else
    result = 'something else';
```

Comment: Does the code you posted work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: hasOwnProperty doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't check whether a filter with a given name exists. I'd rather have a function like hasOwnFilter, that's what I'm looking for at least.

Comment: @trevor $injector.has() didn't work for me, might it be new in Angular 1.3? I'm using version 1.2, otherwise that's pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Jonathan's answers is also acceptable, but I wanted to find a way to check if a filter exists without using a try catch.

You can see if a filter exists like this:

```
return $injector.has(filterName + 'Filter');
```

The 'Filter' suffix is added by angular internally, so you must remember to add it or you will always return false

Comment: This does work only if the filter is defined in the same angular module.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

This seems to work for me.

```
var getFilterIfExists = function(filterName){
  try {
    return $filter(filterName);
  } catch (e){
    return null;
  }
};
```

Then you can do a simple if check on the return value.

```
// Somewhere in the code
var myInput = 'localize';
var filter = getFilterIfExists(myInput);
if (filter) { // Check if this is filter name or a filter string
  value = filter(value);
}
```

## Bonus

If you are looking to parse apart a filter string for example `'currency:"USD$":0'` you can use the following

```
var value; // the value to run the filter on
// Get the filter params out using a regex
var re = /([^:]*):([^:]*):?([\s\S]+)?/;
var matches;
if ((matches = re.exec(myInput)) !== null) {
    // View your result using the matches-variable.
    // eg matches[0] etc.
    value = $filter(matches[1])(value, matches[2], matches[3]);
}
```

### Pull it all together

Wish there was a more elegant way of doing this with angular however there doesn't seem to be.

```
// Somewhere in the code
var myInput = 'localize';
var value; // the value to run the filter on


var getFilterIfExists = function(filterName){
  try {
    return $filter(filterName);
  } catch (e){
    return null;
  }
};
var filter = getFilterIfExists(this.col.cellFilter);
if (filter) { // Check if this is filter name or a filter string
  value = filter(value);
} else {
  // Get the filter params out using a regex
  // Test out this regex here https://regex101.com/r/rC5eR5/2
  var re = /([^:]*):([^:]*):?([\s\S]+)?/;
  var matches;
  if ((matches = re.exec(myInput)) !== null) {
      // View your result using the matches-variable.
      // eg matches[0] etc.
      value = $filter(matches[1])(value, matches[2], matches[3]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
var filter = $filter(myInput);
if (filter)
    result = filter(contentToProcess);
else
    result = 'something else';
```

Undefined and null values are treated as `false` in JS, so this should work in your case.

Comment: $filter(myInput) throws an exception in case it doesn't exist. I could write a wrapper function though to check for exceptions and return the filter or null based on that in case there's no other alternative.